# How to compare times using specific lengths in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, duration, strftime

I have event times stored in the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

What I am trying to do is find all instances of Event where it occurs more than 7 hours after the preceding Trigger.  I am not sure the easiest way to do this after reading the SQLite Date documentation. I guess I will have to use strftime somehow, but I'm really not sure how to approach it.

This is the basic query I'd have to build off of:

`SELECT * FROM Event WHERE Event.DateTime (is more than 7 hours after) (SELECT Trigger.DateTime FROM Trigger WHERE Event.DateTime > Trigger.DateTime)`

I have the test data currently set up like so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Event";
CREATE TABLE "Event" ("DateTime" TEXT, "ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE );
INSERT INTO "Event" VALUES('2000-01-01 08:00:00',1);
INSERT INTO "Event" VALUES('2000-01-01 09:00:00',2);
INSERT INTO "Event" VALUES('2000-01-01 14:00:00',3);
INSERT INTO "Event" VALUES('2000-01-01 15:00:00',4);
INSERT INTO "Event" VALUES('2000-01-01 20:00:00',5);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Trigger";
CREATE TABLE "Trigger" ("DateTime" TEXT, "ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE );
INSERT INTO "Trigger" VALUES('2000-01-01 00:00:01',1);
INSERT INTO "Trigger" VALUES('2000-01-01 10:00:01',2);
```

so it should return 1, 2 and 5 from the events since those are the ones that are over 7 hours after a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you want to test the Event.DateTime against the Trigger.DateTime twice? I think this should work just as well:

```
SELECT * FROM Event 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Trigger 
             WHERE datetime(Event.DateTime,'+7 hours') > Trigger.DateTime)
```

**UPDATE**

Since you only want to compare to the latest trigger, it would be something more like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Event 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT MAX(Trigger.DateTime) newest FROM Trigger 
             HAVING datetime(Event.DateTime,'-7 hours') > newest)
```

**Edit**

```
SELECT * FROM Event 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Trigger 
                 WHERE datetime(Event.DateTime,'-7 hours') <= Trigger.DateTime)

SELECT * FROM Event 
WHERE datetime(Event.DateTime,'-7 hours') > 
            (SELECT MAX(Trigger.DateTime) newest FROM Trigger)
```

**Edit2**

```
SELECT * FROM Event 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Trigger 
                 WHERE Trigger.DateTime BETWEEN datetime(Event.DateTime,'-7 hours') AND Event.DateTime)

SELECT * FROM Event 
WHERE datetime(Event.DateTime,'-7 hours') > 
            (SELECT MAX(Trigger.DateTime) newest FROM Trigger
             WHERE Trigger.DateTime < Event.DateTime)
```

Comment: like the other response, the logic of this makes sense, but it doesn't appear to be working right, even if i switch the +7 to -7, which I *think* is the correct way

Comment: @Damon, You have two triggers in your table, so if either of those more than 7 hours away, it will return. You need to filter the trigger table so that you only get the trigger that you're interested in. You're probably right about the -7 instead of +7 though ^^;

Comment: is <= assigning a variable? I've never seen that..  your statement bugged me saying you can't have HAVING w/o GROUP BY, tried w/where instd of having, and w/ `GROUP BY Trigger.DateTime HAVING...` but that returns everything except the last Event..

Comment: @Damon, <= is 'less than or equal to'. You don't need a group by, here, so I've added a couple of ways to do it without the having. Either of the edits should work for you...

Comment: it seems to be only checking the most recent trigger, on the table as a whole (rather than the one preceding the Events as they're being checked, which is what I want).  I feel like the first one in your edit should be giving me exactly what I need, though! esp cause i tested the `Select 1 From Trigger` part separately and it responded correctly. but it just returns 20:00:00.. not the morning ones

Comment: @Damon, in Edit2, the first query will check triggers including one that might have the same time as the event. The second query will exclude a trigger at the same time as the event, though you can include it by using <= instead of < in the where for the subquery.

Comment: the second one does exactly what i need!

Comment: @Damon, Ah, the order of the operands matters with between. I've fixed the first query to reflect this...

Comment: oh nice! that's good to know i was kinda confused why the first one wasn't working since it did seem perfect logic-wise. now they're both doing their good.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM Event 
WHERE datetime(Event.DateTime,'+7 hours') > (SELECT Trigger.DateTime FROM Trigger 
                                           WHERE Event.DateTime > Trigger.DateTime)
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working.. it seems to just cut eliminate consecutive Events 7 hours before the first Trigger.. or something. Not quite sure what it's doing tbh.  I didn't realize the datetime function was that straightforward, though.. that's pretty cool